# How do I integrate Wordpress into a web app using namespaces?

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces

I'm integrating Wordpress into an existing web app. To retrieve posts I'm including wp-load.php which causes function collisions. This is the structure of the web app:

```
<?php
/* web app code */

include('wordpress/wp-load.php'); //collision happens here

/* web app code */
?>
```

How can I use namespaces to avoid function collisions?

Comment: It might be easier writing code to access the wordpress db directly.